# Cannot add objects to a Mockito Spy of a List

Tags: java, arraylist, mockito

I have a unit test which for <reasons> creates a **Mockito.Spy** of a list instead of using a regular list. Later in the test, it uses Mockito.verify to check what methods were called on the list. However, it's failing in the preparation step with a `NullPointer Exception`.

Firstly the basic case, here I just add an int to an ArrayList and as you would expect, nothing special happens except that the object is added.

```
ArrayList<Integer> idlist1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
idlist1.add(39);
```

Now the actual case of this test is the same except that a Mockito Spy is created. The default behaviour of the Spy is to call the actual method on the list, so I'd expect the same as above, but in fact, it fails when it tries to `add`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> idlist2 = Mockito.spy(new ArrayList<Integer>());
idlist2.add(39);
```

The error message says:

> NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "elementData" is null"

and in the debugger, I can see that this gets to ArrayList::add, but then `add(e, elementData, 0)` fails because elementData is null. In the constructor `ArrayList()` it should be set to an empty array, but something about the Spy must be setting it to null again somehow.

The first possible solution is to just not make a Spy on the List. Fair enough, but I'd like to understand this error message because I'm guessing this problem could occur with other spied objects too.

A second possible solution is to just add objects to a real list before making a Spy of it, but again I'd like to understand what's going on here.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `spy(ArrayList.class)`? `spy` does not wrap an object, it gets the object's class and creates a new instance from it, then copying over state

Comment: Actually I copied and pasted your code to my test and It works.

Comment: Maybe it is related to your mockito version I dont know details. Can you put stacktrace?

Comment: jdk17 and Mockito 3.3.3, if they are relevant. It sounds like for you it behaves as I would expect!
The stacktrace just has my test method (run by JUnit, if that's relevant) -> ArrayList.add(e) -> ArrayList.add(e, elementData, 0). The interception by Mockito shows in the debugger but not in the stacktrace.

Comment: On my system, the returned mock contains an error indicating an InvocationTarget exception on creation of the mock. No idea why this exception isn't propagated.

Comment: Mockito 3.3.3 is quite old (4 years). Try using a current version (5.10.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
   List lst = new ArrayList<Integer>()
   lst.add(39);
   List<Integer> idlist2 = Mockito.spy(lst);
```

Comment: That's what I meant with the final paragraph. But if the method under test tries to add things to the list it's given, then that will throw NullPointerExceptions too.